# How to find first element in sorted list which has distance bigger than 19.0f?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

In sorted list of std::pair which are sorted in ascending order by distance from origin point

```
pair<float,float> origin;
list<pair<float,float> > points;
float distance=19.0f;
```

How to find first element in list which has distance bigger than distance(19.0f) ?
How to apply on list binary search ? ( Iteration is not efficient enough, list is long) ?
Is there more elegant solution ?

Comment: You need a random access container (like std::vector) to do binary search. So I'm afraid binary search on a std::list is not possible. Maybe you should use a std::multiset instead?

Comment: @john: possibly just a `set` if duplicates are not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

A list is not really appropriate for binary search. This is due to the fact that you can only access elements in a list **sequentially** (you can only acces element `k` from element `k-1`), so if you must use a list, you have no other choice than to search linearly for th first element that is bigger than `distance`.

If you want to do a binary search you could use containers such as [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) that allow for direct access of elements (as in `myvector[i]`)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do binary search on a linked list. Consider replacing it by a `vector` or `multiset`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't perform binary search on a linked list efficiently, because the random access time is `O(n)`, whereas `O(1)` is required for binary search to work properly.

You need to iterate through the list, there is no other way, unless you choose a different datastructure.

Answer (score 2):

Use [find_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/). As previously said, `binary_search` can not be used on `std::list` since you can't access a random element in a list.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`boost::flat_set`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost/container/flat_multiset.html) which implements semantics of an ordered container on top of regular vector.

Answer (score 0):

> How to find first element in list which has distance bigger than distance(19.0f)? How to apply on list binary search? (Iteration is not efficient enough, list is long)

As several other answerers have said, binary search won't work on a `std::list`; but if you change your `list` to a `vector`, then the algorithm you are looking for is spelled **[`std::partition_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_point).**

```
using Point = std::pair<float, float>;
float distance_between(Point, Point);

Point origin(0, 0);
std::vector<Point> points = { some stuff... };

// sort in ascending order by distance from origin point
std::sort(
    points.begin(), points.end(),
    [&](const auto& p1, const auto& p2) {
        return distance_between(origin, p1) < distance_between(origin, p2);
    }
);
```

Now here's the part you want to know:

```
// find first element with distance bigger than 19.0f
auto it = std::partition_point(
    points.begin(), points.end(),
    [&](const auto& pt) {
        return distance_between(origin, pt) < 19.0f;
    }
);
```

The returned iterator will be such that:

```
if (it > points.begin()) {
    assert(distance_between(origin, *(it-1)) < 19.0f);
}
if (it < points.end()) {
    assert(distance_between(origin, *it) >= 19.0f);
}
```